# Powershell get unique entry of first column of an array

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm trying to get unique entries from reading out Filepermissions.

I got the following code snippet. It gives me a list with 2 arrays, one Identityreference and one FileSystemRights.

```
$ACLFile = Get-Acl -Path $dir -Filter Access | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access | Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -like "EBK\*"} | Select-Object IdentityReference, FileSystemRights
$ACLFile = $ACLFile.IdentityReference | select -unique
```

Now what I did here only gives me IdentityReference as a result but i need both. If I remove the `$ACLFile.IdentityReference` and just write `$ACLLFile` it removes duplicates from the FileSystemRights columns but I want only the other column as indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `Sort-Object` here:

```
$ACLFile | Sort-Object IdentityReference -unique
```

However, there are issues with this approach alone. You will lose your additional `FileSystemRights` property value for the duplicate `IdentityReference`. Are you wanting to combine all `FileSystemRights` belonging to the same `IdentityReference` into one line?

The following will remove duplicate `IdentityReferences` and combine `FileSystemRights`:

```
$ACLGroup = $ACLFile | Group-Object IdentityReference
$Singles = $ACLGroup.where({$_.count -eq 1}).group
$Duplicates = $ACLGroup.where({$_.count -gt 1})
$ItemizedDuplicates = $Duplicates | foreach {
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{"IdentityReference"=$_.Group.IdentityReference[0]; "FileSystemRights" = $_.Group.FileSystemRights -join ", "}
}
@($ItemizedDuplicates,$Singles)
```

Comment: Nice exactly what i needed.